# How to ask someone for cycling?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, phrases, questions, spoken-english

I moved into a new apartment and don't have any friend in this apartment. I want to make new friends but don't know how to initiate the conversation. I thought asking someone for cycling would be good way to make new friends.

Let me know how to start the conversation with a strangers and how to ask them for cycling so that I can make new friends.

Comment: What do you mean by "for cycling"? Do you mean you'd like to ask them to go cycling with you? In which case "Would you like to go for a bike ride?" would be the usual way to ask. Opinion: It's not very common to ask a stranger to go on cycling with you and I personally would find that a bit odd.

Comment: I agree that verbally asking a stranger would be odd. You could put up a notice asking if anybody is interested in being a *cycling partner*, with a series of tearaway sections with your contact information. Asking strangers in *that* context is socially acceptable.

Comment: Is this a shared apartment? (ie people sharing a living space?)

Comment: I agree with @Bee – to use an English idiom, you are [putting the cart before the horse](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/put-the-cart-before-the-horse). First you make friends, then you ask if any of your new friends want to go cycling with you.

Comment: @smock yeah,its a student accommodation (around 40-50 flats). There are 6 rooms with shared kitchen in each flat but no stays in my flat

Comment: @ jason bassford thanks! sound good :)

Comment: @ bee yes,bike ride :)

Comment: @J.R.thanks! To make friends, I need to initiate the conversation. I am an introvert and want to get rid of my introvert personality. Let me know how to start a conversation with the people you don't know.  :)

Comment: This is an XY problem, and not on topic. The question of "how to start a conversation" is a matter of interpersonal skills, not English Language learning.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question